# Display initialization order of static C++ objects in a program?

Tags: c++, static-initialization, static-order-fiasco

I'm trying to get object dump to print the order that static C++ objects are constructed. I found `-h` for the headers, but I can't seem to get objdump to go any further.

***Program compiled without `init_priority`***

```
$ objdump -h cryptest.exe    
cryptest.exe:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000400238  0000000000400238  00000238  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  0000000000400254  0000000000400254  00000254  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 ...
 10 .init         0000001a  000000000040efd8  000000000040efd8  0000efd8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 ...
```

***Program compiled with `init_priority`***

```
$ objdump -h cryptest.exe    
cryptest.exe:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000400238  0000000000400238  00000238  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  0000000000400254  0000000000400254  00000254  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 ...
 10 .init         0000001a  000000000040efd8  000000000040efd8  0000efd8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 ...
 19 .init_array   000000a8  00000000008e4008  00000000008e4008  002e4008  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

I'm pretty sure my next step is to inspect `.init` and `.init_array`, but I can't seem to get object dump to do it:

```
$ objdump -d .init cryptest.exe 
objdump: '.init': No such file

cryptest.exe:     file format elf64-x86-64
...
```

How do I display the initialization order of static C++ objects in a compiled program?

---

From [How to verify init_priorty for C++ static object initialization order?](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2015-09/msg00175.html) I know I can get some information about it using `objdump -h` or `readelf -S`.

For example, I can see the `init_priority` value associated with an object file:

```
$ objdump -h cryptlib.o
509 .init_array.00275 00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00007da8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA
510 .init_array.00276 00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00007db0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA
511 .init_array.00280 00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00007db8  2**3
```

Above, I see the `init_priority` with its value is present in an object file (`.init_array.00275`), but it does not tell me anything about the variable or the final order once linked into a program.

---

We recently switched to GCC's `init_priority`, so I'm trying to add a QA step to ensure the order of the objects are as specified when it in effect. I also want to see the order of the objects when `init_priority` is not in effect.

---

This is still a problem for us; since adding new self-tests, we can't get a particular string to initialize at the right time, even with `init_priority` and laying out object files in the exact order they should be initialized (see [How to force the linker to honor object file order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34698745)).

There's now an open question on the Binutils mailing list at [Display initialization order of static C++ objects in a library or program?](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2016-01/msg00056.html)

Comment: Also see [AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco).

Answer (score 2):

A `POD` is already initialized in the executable image.

See that `.init` symbol()? Non-`POD` static class instances get initialized by a compiler-generated initialization function, that simply invokes every static object's constructor. The `.init()` function gets invoked when the executable (or the shared object) gets loaded. Its compiler-generated code proceeds to invoke every static object's constructor.

To figure out the initialization order, you'll have to disassemble the `.init`() function, and figure it out based on that.

Comment: Thanks Sam (and sorry about the late reply). Surely there's a better method than disassembling an image. That just seems absurdly ridiculous. I asked the same question on the Binutils mailing list at [Display initialization order of static C++ objects in a library or program?](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2016-01/msg00056.html)

Comment: No, it's not ridiculous. It's simply "undefined". The C++ standard does not specify an explicit order of static object initialization. Although there's nothing wrong with a particular C++ implementation from making this information available, in some way, there's absolutely no requirement for it to do so, so I don't see how a lack of a convenient mechanism to do something that's not required in the first place is "ridiculous". What would be accurately described as "ridiculous", though, is for an application to depend on a particular initialization order. Now that is ridiculous.

Comment: What does the C++ committee have to do with tools essential for Q&A and Security Testing and Evaluation (ST&E)? I fail to see the connection. I guess fortunately for us, we got tools like ***`objdump`*** and ***`nm`*** despite the committee.

Comment: I wasn't aware that objdump and nm are security testing tools, sorry.

Comment: Yes, we use all tools available to us (and not just the ones the C++ committee approves of).