# How to force the linker to honor object file order?

Tags: c++, ld, dyld, static-initialization, static-order-fiasco

I'm catching a Valgrind finding on an uninitialized read. I know exactly where its coming from - its an empty `std::string` declared in a `cpp` file with `static` storage class.

The object file that has the `std::string`'s storage allocation is listed first in the static archive.

```
# string of interest is located in a.o
LIBOBJS := a.o b.o c.o ... x.o y.o z.o

library.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIBOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@
```

In addition, I modified the link recipe to the following (I know it looks silly):

```
program.exe: library.a $(TESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ ./library.a $(TESTOBJS) ./library.a -pthread
```

Above, `library.a` is listed the first time to *ensure* the `std::string` static initializer is the very first initializer that is run. `library.a` is listed a second time to ensure all symbols can be found for the test object since these are single pass linkers.

From Valgrind results on both OS X and Linux, it appears the linkers are not respecting object file order and static initialization.

I have two questions. First, how do I force Apple's linker to respect the order of the object files? Second how do I force GNU's linker to respect the order of the object files?

---

We cannot use linker scripts. The GCC folks specifically tell folks *not* to use them. Plus, I'm not sure of the format on Apple platforms.

---

For what its worth, this is a fallback in case `init_priority` is not available. Unfortunately, its not available on many platforms. Only modern GNU linkers have it, and Apple lacks it completely.

(Our testing goes back quite a ways, from Fedora 1 with GCC 3.2 to Windows 2000).

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the static (global) object initialization order is not defined other than for a specific compile-unit. The solution is to wrap the initalization itself in a function, so that the object is always initialized during that function, rather than as a global variable "everywhere".

Comment: Quoting a library before anything that might need it will accomplish exactly nothing. All the linkers I've used do honour object file order.

Comment: Also see [AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco).